# Query to show all tables and their collation

Tags: mysql, schema, collation

Is there a query that can be run in mysql that shows all tables and their default collation?  Even better if there was on that could show all collations on all columns of all tables.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do it in the BigQuery?

Comment: @Mohith7548 Please start a new question rather than commenting on a decade old answer.

Comment: try it with a semicolon if this doesn't work lol

Answer (score 19):

Bear in mind that collation can be defined to tables and also to columns.

A column's collation might be different to its parent table. Here is a query to get the collation from tables (not columns)

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Answer (score 7):

Output information(status) about all tables in the database as "phpmyadmin":

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your_db_name;
```

Comment: Because it's required parameter in [mysql show table status](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html).

Just so you can not select a table, you always need to know from which database it is. Name of the tables is not unique, in different databases you can have tables with the same name. Therefore, to remove ambiguity, it is necessary to specify the base.

Answer (score -1):

Run this to see columns that not matching database collation. If you want to use these columns in your query and conditions you have to use COLLATE hint to match.

```
SELECT 
     CLM.[TABLE_CATALOG]
    ,CLM.[TABLE_SCHEMA]
    ,CLM.[TABLE_NAME]
    ,CLM.[COLUMN_NAME]
    ,CASE
        WHEN CLM.[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] IS NOT NULL THEN CLM.[DATA_TYPE] + '(' + CASE WHEN CLM.[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] = '-1' THEN 'max' ELSE CAST(CLM.[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] AS NVARCHAR(10)) END + ')'
        ELSE CLM.[DATA_TYPE]
     END AS [DATA_TYPE]
    ,CLM.[CHARACTER_SET_NAME]
    ,CLM.[COLLATION_NAME]
--  ,CLM.* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CLM (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN sys.databases DBS (NOLOCK) ON CLM.[TABLE_CATALOG] = DBS.[name]
WHERE CLM.[COLLATION_NAME] IS NOT NULL AND CLM.[COLLATION_NAME] != DBS.[collation_name]
```

Comment: There is no sys.databases, you have mixed code and mysql, there is syntax error and the query does not work.